# In Track Changes mode, Find is finding matches including in text which has been "deleted"

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, text-editing

NB this is Word 2007.

So hopefully the question is fairly self-explanatory. I'm editing a document with Track Changes on, but I'm hoping to do quite a lot of Find-and-Replace. However, these efforts are being somewhat hampered by the fact that text which I have previously "deleted" (i.e. with red strikethrough) is being identified in these searches.

This doesn't seem to me to be what I've normally experienced, although I don't use Track Changes all that often. I wondered whether there might be some configuration which I can change... but if so I haven't found it yet.

Comment: You need to change the display to "Final" on the reviewing toolbar, or whatever it looks like in Word 2007, for the search to not include the deleted text.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've now found that "Final" option (and "Final showing markup"). But in fact I want to see the markup as well. I think I've found a halfway house: "Final showing markup" combined with "Show Revisions in balloons". I'm supposing that is the closest I can get. Really the Find/Find-and-Replace dialogs should have a simple option when in Track Changes mode, letting you choose ...

Comment: I don't know of other options than that, so I've summarized this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Find tool will search the visible text in the document, so you need
to either :

- Not display this text with the display mode of
  "Final" (and "Final showing markup")
- Move the deleted text outside with the option of
  "Show Revisions in balloons".